# Find $P(X_1 > \max(X_2, X_3)| X_1, X_2, X_3 \geq d)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have three independent random variables $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$.
I am trying to derive the probability that $P(X_1 > \max(X_2, X_3)| X_1, X_2, X_3 \geq d)$.

Here, pdf of $X_1$: $f_{x_1} = \frac{1}{\alpha_1} e^{-\frac{x_1}{\alpha_1}}$. For, $X_2$ and $X_3$: $f_{x_2} = \frac{1}{\alpha_2} e^{-\frac{x_2}{\alpha_2}}$ and $f_{x_3} = \frac{1}{\alpha_3} e^{-\frac{x_3}{\alpha_3}}$, respectively.

I start as: $P(X_1 > X_2) P(X_1 > X_3)$
Then writing $P(X_1 > X_2) $ as:  $\int_\gamma^{\infty} \int_{\gamma}^{x_2} f_{x_1, x_2} dx_1 dx_2$. Am I doing it correctly

Comment: 1. If one does not assume a common distribution, one can only write down explicit but untractable formulas. 2. If one does assume a common distribution without atoms, by a symmetry argument, the answer is always $\frac13$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Original question

Let $\wedge\equiv\min$ and $\vee\equiv\max$. First, note that
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{1}>X_{2}\vee X_{3}\mid X_{1}\wedge X_{2}\wedge X_{3}\geq d)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_{1}>X_{2}\vee X_{3},\,X_{1}\wedge X_{2}\wedge X_{3}\geq d)}{\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\wedge X_{2}\wedge X_{3}\geq d)}.
$$
The denominator is
\begin{multline*}
\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\wedge X_{2}\wedge X_{3}\geq d)=\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\geq d)\mathbb{P}(X_{2}\geq d)\mathbb{P}(X_{3}\geq d)\\
=\left(1-\mathbb{P}(X_{1}<d)\right)\left(1-\mathbb{P}(X_{2}<d)\right)\left(1-\mathbb{P}(X_{3}<d)\right)\\
=\left(1-F_{X_{1}}(d-)\right)\left(1-F_{X_{2}}(d-)\right)\left(1-F_{X_{3}}(d-)\right).
\end{multline*}
Assuming the r.v.s admit probability densities,
\begin{multline*}
\mathbb{P}(X_{1}>X_{2}\vee X_{3},\,X_{1}\wedge X_{2}\wedge X_{3}\geq d)\\
=\mathbb{P}(X_{1}>X_{2}\vee X_{3},\,X_{1}\geq d,\,X_{2}\geq d,\,X_{3}\geq d)\\
=\int_{d}^{\infty}\int_{d}^{\infty}\int_{d\vee x_{2}\vee x_{3}}^{\infty}f_{X_{1}}(x_{1})f_{X_{2}}(x_{2})f_{X_{3}}(x_{3})dx_{1}dx_{2}dx_{3}.
\end{multline*}

## Common distribution with no atoms

If the r.v.s are i.i.d., then by relabelling them we see that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}>X_{2}\vee X_{3}\mid A\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X_{2}>X_{1}\vee X_{3}\mid A\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X_{3}>X_{1}\vee X_{2}\mid A\right)
$$
where $A\equiv\{X_{1}\wedge X_{2}\wedge X_{3}\geq d\}$.
The relabelling argument above is also referred to as a "symmetry" argument.
If in addition the r.v.s. admit admit no atoms, these three events
partition the sample space (i.e., exactly one has to occur).
Therefore, each one has probability $1/3$. 
In particular,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}>X_{2}\vee X_{3}\mid X_{1}\wedge X_{2}\wedge X_{3}\geq d\right)=\frac{1}{3}.
$$

Comment: Do u mean $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\wedge X_{2}\wedge X_{3}\geq d)$?

Comment: @d.k.o.: +1 yes I did. The dangers of copy and paste!

Comment: Thank you @parsiad for the answer. I am a bit confused about the lower integration limit. Given that, $f(x_1)$, $f(x_2)$ and $f(x_3)$ are independent and have the same pdf: $f(x_1) = \frac{1}{\alpha} e^{(-\frac{x}{\alpha})}$, where $\alpha \geq 0$, how should I interpret the lower limit $d$ v $x_2$ v $x_3$?

Comment: @jhon_wick: The lower limit is just a maximum of three numbers. One way to tackle it is to split it up into cases and tackle each case separately.

Comment: Does that mean, $\int \int \int^\infty_d . dx_1 dx_2 dx_3$ + $\int \int \int^\infty_{x_2} . dx_1 dx_2 dx_3$ + $\int \int \int^\infty_{x_3} . dx_1 dx_2 dx_3$ ?

Comment: No, $d \vee x_2 \vee x_3$ just means $\max\{d, x_2, x_3\}$. If I have time I'll update my answer tonight with an explanation.

Comment: @parsiad., thanks so much. will wait.

Comment: @jhon_wick: Updated. There were a lot of places where I could have made a mistake in the algebra, so read carefully. Regardless, the idea is correct.

Comment: By a simple symmetry argument, the answer $\frac13$ is much more general than you make it...

Comment: @Did: I updated my answer to use the symmetry argument instead.

Comment: @parsiad, could you please revert back to the early answer? For my problem, I have different $\alpha$ for three distribution, which did not clarify probably.

Comment: I have updated the questions. Please check @parsiad. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jhon_wick: You can look at the edit history of the question.